# How to pass parameter through href in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to pass parameter from href to controller in laravel. Below is the way I am doing this. But it is generating Page Not Found. Kindly someone help me through this.
Here is my code files:

Route :

```
    Route::get('projects/showall', 'ProjectsController@showall')->name('projects.showall');
```

Controller :

```
public function showall($role){

    if($role == 'admin'){
            dump('hello');
    }
    else{
        dump('hello');
    }
}
```

(blade)view file:

```
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('projects.showall',['role'=> 'admin'])}}"> </i>All Companies</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your route does not accept a parameter. take a look at this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters.

Based on the documentation, if you want to pass a value, you may able to define a parameter in the route. Like this:

```
Route::get('projects/showall/{role}', 'ProjectsController@showall')->name('projects.showall');
```

and call it on the controller :

```
public function showall(Request $request){

    if($request->role == 'admin'){
            dump('hello');
    }
    else{
        dump('hello');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

route :

```
Route::get('projects/showall/{role}', 'ProjectsController@showall')->name('projects.showall');
```

controller :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


public function showall(Request $request,$role){

    if($role == 'admin'){
            dump('hello');
    }
    else{
        dump('hello');
    }
}
```

view:

```
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('projects.showall',['role'=> 'admin'])}}"> </i>All Companies</a>
```